# I am catching exception in a DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler In App.cs so I don't know what line is throwing it

Tags: .net, wpf, exception

This is an exception I am getting.
I am catching it in a a DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler
In App.cs so I don't now what line is throwing it
Any advice on how to track this down and fix it?
There is not inner exception

```
e.Exception.GetBaseException().Message Object 
reference not set to an instance of an object.


e.Exception.StackTrace    
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.MoveToPosition(GeneratorPosition position, GeneratorDirection direction, Boolean allowStartAtRealizedItem, GeneratorState& state)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.Generator..ctor(ItemContainerGenerator factory, GeneratorPosition position, GeneratorDirection direction, Boolean allowStartAtRealizedItem)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator.StartAt(GeneratorPosition position, GeneratorDirection direction, Boolean allowStartAtRealizedItem)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)


void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("App_DispatcherUnhandledException");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("(e == null) = " + (e == null).ToString());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.ToString() " + e.ToString());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.Exception.GetBaseException().Message " + e.Exception.GetBaseException().Message);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.Exception.GetBaseException().InnerException " + e.Exception.GetBaseException().InnerException);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.Exception.GetBaseException().Source " + e.Exception.GetBaseException().Source.ToString());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.Exception.StackTrace " + e.Exception.StackTrace.ToString());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.Exception.GetBaseException().StackTrace " + e.Exception.GetBaseException().StackTrace.ToString());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (e.Exception.InnerException != null)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("InnerException");
        sb.AppendLine(e.Exception.InnerException.Message);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Exception.InnerException.StackTrace))
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (string line in e.Exception.InnerException.StackTrace.Split('\n'))
            {
                sb.AppendLine(line.Trim());
                count++;
                if (count > 3) break;
            }
        }
    }
    sb.AppendLine("OuterException");
    sb.AppendLine(e.Exception.Message);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Exception.StackTrace))
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (string line in e.Exception.StackTrace.Split('\n'))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line.Trim());
            count++;
            if (count > 3) break;
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "App_DispatcherUnhandledException");
    e.Handled = true;
    if (MainWindow != null) MainWindow.Close();
}
```

Comment: Can you run it in the debugger?

Comment: Temporarily comment out your exception handler, or set Visual Studio to break when CLR exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Can you show your exception handler?

Comment: So far I cannot get it to error in the debugger.

Comment: On Visual Studio's **DEBUG** menu, click the **Exceptions** item.  Check the box in the **thrown** column for **Common Language Runtime Exceptions.**

Comment: @Dan Thanks on the Exceptions menu.  From that I found some other problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a line of code like

```
e.Exception.GetBaseException().Message
```

You have to first make sure that GetBaseException() *actually returns an object.*

```
var baseException = e.Exception.GetBaseException();
if (baseException != null)
{
    // Do something with baseException.Message
}
```

This is the problem, according to your stack trace.  I'm skeptical, because the MSDN documentation states that `GetBaseException()` should always return an object (if you are, in fact, handling an actual exception that hasn't been unwound yet).

Comment: Thanks I will try that.  But then I still need to track down where the unhandled exception came from.

Comment: Sure.  But if you fix the problem with the handler, the nature of the original exception should become more apparent (since the new exception is masking the original).

Comment: OK thanks I think I agree.  I just need to get there to verify.

Comment: I could not get it to throw an exception that had a null GetBaseException() to verify but I suspect (hope) this is the answer.